# Is there a full version of Super Smash Flash 2?

Tags: super-smash-flash-2

I have played Super Smash Flash 2 Demo for a while now. I enjoy the game very much, but you can only Brawl there. Like I said, I enjoy the game, but I want do something different using my favourite character (Ichigo :P), other than beating up other opponents. The first version of Super Smash Flash has a lot more characters than the second part, and even has a story mode.

Since the title says "Demo", I'm guessing there is a full version to that game. So I was wondering if any of you guys know about the release date of the full version or where to find it. Please tell say any information you may have. :)

Comment: Oh, and guys, just recently I found a new version of that game. Its in http://www.mcleodgaming.com/viewflash.php?id=6&type=game It is version 0.7

Comment: Most recent update is 0.8b.  Apparently, 0.9 should shortly arrive and with it some major CPU upgrades.  So far, this is one hell of a  game.  It's pretty amazing, considering it's been all done in flash.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that the "demo" is really just a beta version of the game, and that the full game has yet to be released. Check the [official game developer's webpage](http://www.mcleodgaming.com/games.php), and you can see that it will be releasing "demo" updates, which indicated the demo is really just a game in development. The [wiki](http://mcleodgaming.wikia.com/wiki/Super_Smash_Flash_2) also seems to confirm this.